# How do I create a WAR file using NetBeans' generated ant script?

Tags: netbeans, ant, build, build-automation, war

I'm trying to configure an automated build process, and I need to get a WAR file to deploy to Tomcat.  The project was created in Netbeans, which automatically generates an ant script.  I think when I click "Clean and Build Project" from the menu it runs a series of ant targets and generates the WAR that I need.  So does anyone know which ant targets Netbeans runs when you click "Clean and Build Project".  My theory is that I can just run the same targets on my own.  Does that make sense or is there a better way to do it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the 'dist' target to generate the war file that you can distribute to Tomcat.  If you ant to do the equivalent of 'Clean and Build', you can run 'ant clean dist'.